# Tornado with Django

Tags: python, django, tornado

I'm working on Django project (RSS and  Tweet aggregator)

1. how to use tornado with django in this project ( all I need form
   tornado is synchronize "real time update feature")
2. How to use django orm and django forms  with tornado to hmm to do
   things easier with tornado

Comment: Check this out - [Using django inside Tornado web server](http://lincolnloop.com/blog/2009/sep/15/using-django-inside-tornado-web-server/)

Answer (score 21):

Those hacks are no longer necessary as of Tornado 2.0.

Now you can use tornado.wsgi.WSGIContainer to wrap django and run it on tornado. You can even specify that some urls go to tornado and get the async benefits and some go to django!

Please see https://github.com/bdarnell/django-tornado-demo for a

Comment: That demo does not work with recent versions of Tornado. Check out this one: https://github.com/tamasgal/django-tornado

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this:

https://gist.github.com/654157

https://github.com/koblas/django-on-tornado

Comment: may you write more about django-on-tornado please